# Why multisort works only in the first depth of array?

Tags: php

I thought that the function [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) can sort multidimensional array, but this code does not work.

Code:

```
$values = array(0, 2, 1, array(0, 2, 1));
array_multisort($values, SORT_ASC);
var_dump($values);
```

Return:

```
array(4) [
   0 => 0
   1 => 1
   2 => 2
   3 => array(3) [
      0 => 0
      1 => 2 //should be 1
      2 => 1 //should be 2
   ]
]
```

Why the array in array is not sorted? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
sort_recursive($values);
var_dump($values);
```

Output

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 2
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 1
      2 => int 2
```

Function Used

```
function sort_recursive(&$array) {
    sort($array);
    foreach ( $array as &$v ) {
        is_array($v) and sort_recursive($v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is because the `array()` is in a multidimentional form

try this link to see how to sort multidimensional array [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2)